# pthread cleanup function is not getting called

Tags: c, pthreads

i am trying to use pthread clean up function to release the mutex which the cancelled thread is holding

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define SHOW_TECH_CMD_MAX_EXEC_TIME       5 //in secs 
pthread_mutex_t waitMutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t testMutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t waitCond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
void mutex_cleanup_handler(void *arg )
{
   printf("cleanup \n");
   pthread_mutex_unlock( &testMutex );
}
void *execute_on_thread(void *arg);
void *execute_on_thread(void *arg)
{
  pthread_cleanup_push(mutex_cleanup_handler, NULL);
  pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, NULL);
  pthread_mutex_lock( &testMutex );
  while(1)
  {
    printf(".");
  }
  pthread_mutex_lock( &waitMutex );
  pthread_cond_signal( &waitCond );
  pthread_mutex_unlock( &waitMutex );
  pthread_cleanup_pop(1); // even with 1 behavior remains the same
  return (void *) 0;

}
int main( )
{
  pthread_t tid;
  struct timespec   ts;
  int error;
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);
  ts.tv_sec += 5; 
  pthread_create(&tid,NULL,execute_on_thread,NULL);
  pthread_mutex_lock(&waitMutex);
  error = pthread_cond_timedwait(&waitCond, &waitMutex,&ts);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&waitMutex);
  printf("come here 1\n");
  if(error == ETIMEDOUT)
  {
    printf("come here 2\n");
    error = pthread_cancel(tid);
    if(error != 0)
    {
       printf("come here 3\n");
    }
      }
}
```

cleanup function is not getting called itself 
the thread is getting cleared properly , but the cleanup function is not being called

Comment: execute_on_thread() has an incorrect type.

Answer (score 2):

As [Man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cleanup_push.3.html) says:

> The pthread_cleanup_pop() function removes the routine at the top of
>          the stack of clean-up handlers, **and optionally executes it if execute
>          is nonzero.**

Then you have to write:

```
pthread_cleanup_pop(1);
```

Take note that your thread function definition is incorrect

**EDIT**

Using your code, the correction below works.

```
  if(error == ETIMEDOUT)
  {
    printf("come here 2\n");
    error = pthread_cancel(tid);
    pthread_join(tid, NULL);
    if(error != 0)
    {
       printf("come here 3\n");
    }
```

You must wait the thread completion before end of your application.
In your code, after thread cancel request, the application ends immediately.

Comment: even after changing the value from 0 to 1 , the behavior remains the same

Comment: not at all helpful . my question here is that when main thread is cancelling my child thread , clean up function is not getting called

Comment: if i am going to terminate the thread then i dont think i need a clean up function itself

Comment: @manimuthuma In your code you must add `pthread_join(tid, NULL);` after `pthread_cancel` function call. You must wait the thread termination.

Comment: i cancelled the thread , why would i need to wait for the termination

Comment: @manimuthuma When the main thread returns, it terminates the entire process. This includes all other threads. This does not leave time to other thread to complete operations.

Comment: hai LP , the thread got cancelled pthread_Cancel is returning 0

Comment: @manimuthuma Take a look at [Man](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cancel) cancellation is not performed immediately and `pthread_cancel` does not block until the thread is finisched. It simply send a _cancellation request_ to the thread.